# ubuntu12.04 apt-get update issue

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

I got an odd issue on the ubuntu12.04 when I ran `sudo apt-get update` command:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en
Something wicked happened resolving '**proxy3.serd.global.sharp.com.jp:3080**' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

Here's my `/etc/source.list`:

```
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ precise-security multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

And `.basrc` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` content:

```
**HTTP_PROXY=http://account:pwd@myproxy:3080**
**Acquire::http::proxy "http://account:pwd@myproxy:3080/"**;
```

And `/etc/resolve.conf`:

```
namespace 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

I also added Google DNS server ip(8.8.8.8) to the ipv4 DNS configuration, but still failed. Anyone knows why?

Comment: The source list looks strange, do you really have the spaces between `h` and `ttp://`?

Comment: It says you are behind a proxy...

Comment: @January For new users there is a maximum number of links you're allowed to post and I suspect (given the reformatting required here) they were all showing as links before adding the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I blame the proxy.

From here in the UK `proxy3.serd.global.sharp.com.jp` does not resolve but the mirror works fine. Stop using the `sharp.com.jp` proxy and things should start to work. I don't know why you'd want to use a Japanese proxy for a Chinese mirror anyway. Doesn't really make much sense.

---

If you're adamant you know what `proxy3.serd.global.sharp.com.jp` *should* resolve to, run `sudoedit /etc/hosts` in a terminal and add the following as a new line at the end of the file:

```
172.30.124.10    proxy3.serd.global.sharp.com.jp
```

Comment: I work for a Japanese company and it's in the China. In the company i must use jp proxy to connect the network.The browser is ok by using this proxy, but the apt can not work...By a way,there is no space between the h and ttp://

Comment: i just modified this above proxy to 172.30.124.10, the update action is ok now, so DNS error cause this issue. i don't know how to configure the local dns...

Comment: @HarrisHuang If you just want to add a record for this domain, you can do so by editing `/etc/hosts`. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: yeah, as you said, it's ok now. thanks for your help.